# Document Management System and SharePoint

Tags: 2010, document-library, document-set

I have a requirement from my client to store scanned documents with formats like TIFF, GIF, PNG, PDF, .XLSX, DOCX etc and upload into SharePoint. Later they want to Index them and retrieve them as well sort of a Document Management & Archiving system but I have never worked on any DMS product and they want to use SharePoint as DMS product.

Would appreciate the guidance what do I need to do to Index, Store, Archive & Retrieve based on MetaData and search through criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Supriyo mentioned, this is a very broad topic.  However, Microsoft has documented planning for document management in great detail.  Start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263266(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

DMS is a large complex topic with many segments - scanning, taxonomy, metadata, categorizing, indexing, search, archiving, etc.
Here are two posts that provide simple examples to explain it more clearly -

[How to I get paper documents into SharePoint 2010….3 easy options](http://digitalmacgyver.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/how-to-i-get-paper-documents-into-sharepoint-2010-3-easy-options/)

[HomeDocs – How to make your home paperless using SharePoint with integrated imaging and scanning](http://arunkaggarwal.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/homedocs-how-to-make-your-home-paperless-using-sharepoint-with-integrated-imaging-and-scanning/)